# How can we configure parse server with mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform

Actually, I have Installed the necessary software but I couldn't able to pass this step!!! Please, anyone, help me with this...

This is windows 10 with the latest versions of mongoDB,JS and parse server

Starting a MongoDB deployment to test against...{ [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink 'C:\Users\Indium Software.mongodb\versions\mongodb-4.0.8-windows-64' -> 'C:\Users\Indium Software.mongodb\versions\mongodb-current'] errno: -4048, code: 'EPERM', syscall: 'symlink',

This is what the error I am facing with...

Comment: This looks like a permission error. Have you tried running the command as Administrator?

Comment: Yeah, I even tried with using running administrator... But there is no response of starting MongoDB it  just loading but there is no response